# Плавная анимация градиента при наведении

Tags: css, html5, css3, css-animation

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, red, green);
  transition: background 1s;
}

div:hover {
  background: red;
  transition: background 1s;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Как реализовать плавную заливку градиента в 1 цвет (красный) при наведении?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, red, green);
}
div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
div:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Волшебник. Спасибо